# How to overcome null exception when using Linq Count to sort a stringlist?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using an array of string to sort a Linq string list according to the number of words matched from the array.

```
var targets = new string[] { ... }; // obtained via code
var list = = new List<string>(); // obtained via code
list = list.OrderByDescending(u => targets.Count(u.Contains)).ToList();// exception if null
```

The code works perfectly until it encounter a `null string` in `list`. I don't want to omit the nulls just want them sorted at the bottom of list. Is it possible to do this without using another list or intersections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have `null` values be at the end of the list then you need to map them to the lowest value.  In this case the key is `int` so use `int.MinValue`.

```
list = list
  .OrderByDescending(u => u == null ? int.MinValue : targets.Count(u.Contains))
  .ToList();
```

Rather than using this pattern though I would suggest you use `List.Sort` directly.  The `Sort` method can be done in place and doesn't require the allocation of a brand new `List<string>`